# How to fetch a maximum length in mongo db using aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have records in mongo so that each one has a field called `url` and I'd like to know the top 10 counters of the longest URLs. How could I do it please? Tried to start with:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {},
            maxUrlLength: {
                $max: "url"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1,
            },
        }
    }   
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately the aggregation framework has no strlen operator. You might have to use MapReduce.

Comment: You could even store the length of the url in the mongo document itself when you are inserting a new record. Then use that to get the desired results.